# Command not configured for JavaScript (JSX)! Scrimba 'learn react' course

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im currently doing the 'learn react' course on scrimba. I've run into a problem at the very beginning

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

When I try to run the code above (in atom), i get 'Command not configured for JavaScript (JSX)!' error. Also when i created a react project, after opening the default .js files I got the same error. Any help appreciated!

update: changing filename to .jsx 'fixed' the above error but now im getting

```
 SyntaxError: /Users/dmccaul/.atom/packages/script/node_modules/.bin/babel: Unexpected token (4:16)
  2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 | 
> 4 | ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
    |                 ^
```

Comment: what do you mean by "run the code above"? In node.js?

Comment: oh, no im using atom

Comment: @ChristianFritz doesn't mean the text editor you're using; in almost all cases, that doesn't matter. Instead, he's asking if you're running your code with NodeJS, a JavaScript runtime

Comment: I'm actually not sure, is there a way to check?

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely coming from the `atom-script` plugin, see [this issue](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/issues/630) and [this commit](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/commit/4390c94d143ad2ca4cb323e18f901beff4f216ca). You will the `babel-node` package to get it working.

Comment: I installed language-babel to no avail. Changing the file to .jsx seems to have gotten rid of that error.
However the program as a whole still isnt working. my html file is as follows

`<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.pack.jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
but hello world is not showing up

Comment: Is `index.pack.jsx` the correct output file, not something like `bundle.js`?

Comment: I dont have a bundle.js file created

Comment: Without knowing the layout and config of your project I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that, but if you post some of those details (possibly in a new question) someone should be able to help.

Comment: ill draft up a new question so, thanks for the help so far! Do you have any idea where the extra error i edited into the above question could be coming from?

Comment: Babel itself is just a transpiler, it doesn't know what you want to transpile and how you want to do it. You'll need the package `@babel/preset-react` as well, and to configure babel to use that, for example `{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"] }` in your `.babelrc`. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react/